# Dynamically created input type file not moving the uploaded files

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created an dynamic upload form where user clicks add more and a new input type field is created

```js
< script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" > < /script> <
script type = "text/javascript" >
  var counter = 0;
$(function() {
  $('p#add_field').click(function() {
    counter += 1;
    $('#container').append(
      '<strong>ಇತರೆ ದಾಖಲಾತಿಗಳು. ' + counter + '</strong><br />' +
      '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="dynfields[]' + '" type="file" /><br />');

  });
}); <
/script>
```

```html
<div id="container" class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <p id="add_field"><a href="#"><span>+ Click To Add</span></a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

MY php code

```
    if (!empty($_POST['dynfields'])) {
foreach ( $_POST['dynfields'] as $key=>$value ) {
$values = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
$file1 = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['values']['name'];
 $file_loc = $_FILES['values']['tmp_name'];
 $file_size = $_FILES['values']['size'];
 $file_type = $_FILES['values']['type'];
 $folder="../uploads/Dodballapur_PDF/";

 move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$file1);
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO other_files_dod (id,file1,type,size,Upload_Date1) VALUES ('','$file1','$file_type','$file_size',NOW())" );

//}
}
```

I am not able to analyze what mistake i am making here, need help on this. 
1) Not able to move the uploaded files to the mentioned folder location.
2) Database is also not inserted

Am i passing the wrong file name ??

Comment: what does https://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and `mysql_error()` for the query show? If errors, update your post to contain them

Comment: In addition to what Funk says, also, move away from using the dead `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: after more files selecting , you have to submit button to submit there , you don't have?

Comment: i am not getting any errors for this rest of the code executes fine along with this, anyways i am able to rectify the mistake i was passing the values and changed my for loop to this

`foreach($_FILES['dynfields']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){`

also changed the if condition to this
`if(isset($_FILES['dynfields'])){`

and i passed the **dynfields** everywhere

Comment: My one more question in my form how do i add the remove button for dynamically created input type fields

`<script type = "text/javascript" >
  var counter = 0;
$(function() {
  $('p#add_field').click(function() {
    counter += 1;
    $('#container').append(
      '<strong>ಇತರೆ ದಾಖಲಾತಿಗಳು. ' + counter + '</strong><br />' +
      '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="dynfields[]' + '" type="file" /><br />');

  });
}); <
/script>`

Any help here highly appreciated thank you :)

Comment: @ Mohit Kumar 13 yes i have not mentioned the submit code here, Finally i am doing the form submission i have lot more input types along with this one

Comment: then check https://www.codexworld.com/add-remove-input-fields-dynamically-using-jquery/

Comment: Thanks Mohit Kumar i adjusted the code according to my requirement it is very easy to understand [link] (https://www.codexworld.com/add-remove-input-fields-dynamically-using-jquery/)[link] this link worked like a charm

Comment: How can i add the progress bar for the existing code snippet as i don't want to change the whole code and start again only for this purpose of adding progress bar,

This will complete all my requirement need help in this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final Working code

```js
< script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" > < /script>

  <
  script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var maxField = 3; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="file" name="dynfields[]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><font color="red"><p id="remove_field"><span><strong>X Remove</strong></span></p></font></a></div>'; //New input field html 
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    $(addButton).click(function() { //Once add button is clicked
      if (x < maxField) { //Check maximum number of input fields
        x++; //Increment field counter
        $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
      }
    });
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e) { //Once remove button is clicked
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
      x--; //Decrement field counter
    });
  }); <
/script>
```

```html
<div id="container" class="field_wrapper">
  <div class="controls">
    <!-- <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/> -->
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">
      <p id="add_field"><span><strong>+ ಇತರೆ ದಾಖಲಾತಿಗಳು</strong></span></p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

My PHP script

```
`

if(isset($_FILES['dynfields'])){
        $errors= array();
        foreach($_FILES['dynfields']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
            $file_name = $key.$_FILES['dynfields']['name'][$key];
            $file_size =$_FILES['dynfields']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp =$_FILES['dynfields']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type=$_FILES['dynfields']['type'][$key];  
            if($file_size > 10097152){
                $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
            }       
            $query="INSERT INTO other_files_dod (id,file1,type,size,Upload_Date1) VALUES ('','$file_name','$file_type','$file_size',NOW())";
            $desired_dir="../uploads/Dodballapur_PDF/";
            if(empty($errors)==true){
                if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                    mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
                }
                if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"../uploads/Dodballapur_PDF/".$file_name);
                }else{                                  //rename the file if another one exist
                    $new_dir="../uploads/Dodballapur_PDF/".$file_name.time();
                     rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
                }
                mysql_query($query);            
            }else{
                    print_r($errors);
            }
        }
        if(empty($error)){
            echo "Success";
        }
    }
```

`